# In vs code django rest framework not showing autocomplete

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

This is my setting.json

```
{
"files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/bin/python",
"python.analysis.indexing": true,

}
```

Why vscode not show autocomplete for django rest framework?

Comment: first of all, ensure that `drf` is installed properly, by `pip show djangorestframework` then check the related python version connected with the `pip` by `pip -V`. Now check the python interpreter version on the vs code at the bottom of the page. you have to select the version that was the same with `pip -V` python version.